# Problem with getCostmapCopy() in Hydro

Tags: navigation, ros-fuerte, ros-hydro, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm trying to move code from Fuerte to Hydro. In the old code there was:

```
costmap_ros_->getCostmapCopy(costmap_);
```

but this function is no longer exist in Hydro. How Can I replace this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/161536/problem-with-getcostmapcopy()-in-hydro/) by [Stefano Primatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/9136/stefano-primatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 402 on 2014-05-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of accessing a copy, you can just access the costmap itself with getCostmap()

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1